# AcroField and superscript

Tags: itext

I am setting the text value of a AcroField in a PDF template with text that comes from another LOB system. This works fine. However, the customer recently asked that we be able to support superscripted text in the fields.

My first thought, since it would require the least amount of re-coding, would be to allow the customer to specify some markup in the LOB system (e.g. 'normal text ^Ssuper scripted text^S more normal text' would produce 'normal text <sup>super scripted text</sup> more normal text') that I would look for in my application and then set the font on the substring to be smaller and then set the vertical offset. I have found and used examples where I can set the font on a AcroField but I cannot seem to get a clear answer on if I can set the font for a substring. I know we [can do it using Chunks](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/superscript-subscript.html), but that looks like it would require a significant amount of retooling in our templates and the code that is creating the documents.

I am looking for a push in the right direction more than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Rich text might be what you are after.

iText allows you to set a rich text value using `AcroFields.setFieldRichValue`.

If you want to use this, you can find a description of this rich text in section 12.7.3.4 *Rich Text Strings* in [the PDF specification ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Please take notice of the JavaDocs comment of that method, though:

```
/**
 * Sets the rich value for the given field.  See <a href="http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf">PDF Reference</a> chapter 
 * 12.7.3.4 (Rich Text) and 12.7.4.3 (Text Fields) for further details. Note that iText doesn't create an appearance for Rich Text fields.
 * So you either need to use XML Worker to create an appearance (/N entry in the /AP dictionary), or you need to use setGenerateAppearances(false) to tell the viewer
 * that iText didn't create any appearances.
 * @param name  Field name
 * @param richValue html markup 
 * @return success/failure (will fail if the field isn't found, isn't a text field, or doesn't support rich text)
 * @throws DocumentException
 * @throws IOException 
 * @since 5.0.6
 */
public boolean setFieldRichValue(String name, String richValue) throws DocumentException, IOException
```

Thus, use `setGenerateAppearances(false)` to inform the PDF viewer that it shall create an appearance from the rich text; alternatively, you may try and create the appearance yourself. I think, though, that there is a reason why iText does not yet contain code to automatically create that appearance; most probable it is not exactly trivial to do so the same way as Adobe Reader does.

**PS:** for the use as super script the specification explicitly mentions

> **vertical-align** *decimal* An amount by which to adjust the baseline of the enclosed text. A positive value indicates a superscript; a negative value indicates a subscript. The value is of the form pt, optionally preceded by a sign, and followed by “pt”.

Probably you'll want to combine that with

> **font-size** *decimal* The font size of the enclosed text. The value is of the form pt.

Comment: I was looking at that but did not see the <sup> markup listed so I assumed it wasn't supported.

Comment: Use the vertical-align attribute of a <span>

Comment: I have tried to get the rich text to work but apparently iText does not support flattening rich text fields which I need to do.

Comment: From the JavaDoc I quoted in my answer: **Note that iText doesn't create an appearance for Rich Text fields. So you either need to use XML Worker to create an appearance (/N entry in the /AP dictionary), or you need to use setGenerateAppearances(false) to tell the viewer that iText didn't create any appearances.** For flattening the appearances are required.

Comment: I tried the setGenerateApparances = false; and that didn't work. I was able to work around this issue though through JavaScript on the PDf side.

Comment: @El Hombre. How exactly did you fix it in JavaScript please?

Comment: I stashed an array of fields that needed to be superscripted as a var in the document, then when the PDF is opened the JS loops through the array and added the superscript markup as needed. It is a hack but it works. There are probably better ways, but I was far enough down a 'bad path' that it was the only option.

Comment: ^More specifically, any sub string that needed superscript I wrapped in a (s) from the source (e.g. "This would be normal text (s)and this is superscripted(s) text"). I then stored that field as a var and used JavaScript substring(), added superscript markup, then moved next.